connecting two marks in hf-tikz with a line
How could I go about connecting two marks in hf-tikz with a line?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin{a-1}a\tikzmarkend{a-1}&b&c\\
    d&e&\tikzmarkin{a-2}f\tikzmarkend{a-2}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}



Using the package hf-tikz alone I don't think that is possible. However, as stated in the package documentation (please refer to the example in Section 2.2) you can use the environment tikzpicture from the package tikz with the following options: overlay and remember picture.
I would also have used this option - \usetikzlibrary{calc} - within the tikz package to manually adjust the connection line location.
Consider the following MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % For manual adjustment of the line location.
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5em} % Adjust horizontal spacing between letters.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % Adjust vertical spacing between rows.

\begin{document}

% Drawing your figure.
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin{a-1}a\tikzmarkend{a-1}&b&c\\
    d&e&\tikzmarkin{a-2}f\tikzmarkend{a-2}
\end{array}
\]

% Drawing the connection line.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[green, thick] 
        ($(a-1.south east) + (2.5mm, -3.5mm)$) -- ($(a-2.south) + (.5mm, 1mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The above code produces the following result:

I hope this solution covers your needs.

Nice answer! I'm curious, do you know a way to make the manual adjustments so they connect properly? Currently it looks like it was done by eye. I'm wondering if there is a way to find the x and y coordinates of the horizontal and vertical boundaries of the cells.

With a little research I found something interesting under the tikzmark documentation (refer to Chapter 2). If I'm interpreting correctly, I think you can reference a coordinate with pic cs and use it like: ($(pic cs:a-1)$) instead of ($(a-1.south east) + (2.5mm, -3.5mm)$). However I've tried now and it does not seem to work very properly without a little "fine-tuning" of your own.

Thank you for helping explore this topic

You welcome. If you need anything more, feel free to ask.

You could use the tikzmark library instead of hf-tikz:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
 
\tikzset{
  every tikzmarknode/.style={fill=red!20,draw=violet,inner sep=5pt,rounded corners=3pt}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \tikzmarknode{a-1}{a} &b&c\\
    d&e&\tikzmarknode{a-2}{f}
\end{array}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[green, thick] (a-1) -- (a-2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I would be inclined to use this approach if I could highlight multiple cells at once with \tikzmarknode. Is this something you could answer in a comment, or maybe I should ask another question?

@Jasper If you need to highlights multiple cells, I would use nicematrix instead.

Thank you, I will check it out

One more quick question: if the green line is more diagonal, how can it be extended so it reaches the rounded corners?

@Jasper shorten <=-1mm,shorten >=-1mm
